# Local $U(1)$ gauge invariance of QED

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, gauge-invariance

The Lagrangian density for QED is

$$ \mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}+\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}-m)\psi $$

with

$$F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu} $$
$$ \bar{\psi}=\gamma^{0}\psi^{\dagger}$$
$$D_{\mu}=\partial_{\mu}+ieA_{\mu}$$

$U(1)$ local gauge transformations are

$$\psi\rightarrow\psi^{'}=e^{-i\alpha(x)}\psi$$
$$A_{\mu}^{'}=A_{\mu}+\frac{1}{e}\partial_{\mu}\alpha(x)$$

I'm trying to see that $\mathcal{L}$ it is invariant under those $U(1)$ transformations, but I finish my calculation with

$$\mathcal{L}^{'}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+e^{-i\alpha(x)}\bar{\psi}[i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}-m-\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\alpha(x)]e^{i\alpha(x)}\psi $$

Any hint will be appreciated thanks

Comment: Hint: Show first that $D_{\mu}\psi$ transforms in a particular simple manner.

Comment: @Qmechanic May it be $D_{\mu}\psi \rightarrow D^{'}_{\mu}\psi^{'}=e^{-i\alpha(x)}D_{\mu}\psi$ ?

Comment: Yes. $\uparrow$

Comment: The spinor term still troubles me, because $\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}-m)\psi$ will go to $e^{i\alpha(x)}\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}D^{'}_{\mu}-m)\psi e^{-i\alpha(x)}=e^{i\alpha(x)}\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}e^{-i\alpha(x)}D_{\mu}\psi-m\psi)e^{-i\alpha(x)}=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}\psi e^{-i\alpha(x)}-m\psi)$

Comment: if $D_{\mu}\psi$ goes to $e^{-i\alpha}D_{\mu}\psi$ and $-m\psi$ goes to $-me^{-i\alpha}\psi$ then you're done aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I was double counting $e^{-i\alpha(x)}$ in the common factor, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing that the partial derivative in $D_\mu$ acts on the phase factor. If you start only with the phase transformation of the Dirac term:

$$\mathcal{L}_D' = \bar \psi e^{i\alpha(x)} \left[ i\gamma^\mu(\partial_\mu + ieA_\mu) - m \right] \psi e^{-i\alpha(x)} $$

you can *almost* pull the $e^{i\alpha(x)} $ through and cancel them. However, the $\partial_\mu=\partial/\partial x^\mu$ acts on $ e^{i\alpha(x)} $ and gives you an additional term (product, then chain rule). So after canceling, $\partial_\mu \rightarrow \partial_\mu + $ something with $\alpha(x)$. Then perform the $A_\mu \rightarrow A_\mu'$ substitution, and the terms should exactly cancel out.

Comment: I was double counting an exponential factor, I had your answer in mind, however as it is the only one I will accept it

Comment: @Nivalth: Thanks a lot, but you didn't have to accept it if it didn't help you. Qmechanic and twistor59 also deserve some credit, but unfortunately you don't get points for comments.

Comment: Hi, I've been thinking a little about this. Does the recipe goes as follows? 1) $\mathcal{L}_{QED}$ then I impose the local $U(1)$ gauge transformations on the spinors and 2)this tells me how exactly should $A_{\mu}$ transform in order to keep the Lagrangian density invariant?